# Encrypt & Decrypt Sqlite file (Using Core Data)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite, core-data, encryption

I am using a Pre-Populated **SQLite Database with Core Data.**

My problem is that i want to **encrypt sqlite database file generated by Core Data**. I cannot encrypt data because there are lots of queries involved in project. So, only i want to encrypt file.

I have already gone through lots of forum, source code, libraries but couldn't figure out much.

I have already used libraries provided by this [iphone blog](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/02/strong-encryption-for-cocoa-cocoa-touch.html) as well but that libraries are buggy.

If you have some core solution then please help.

Thanks,
Tariq

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data Protection:

Data protection is a feature available for iOS 4 devices that offer hardware encryption: iPhone 4, iPhone 3GS,  iPod touch (3rd generation or later), and all iPad models. This article outlines how to enable and verify data protection.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4175

[Link to apple article from way back machine as original link is removed](https://web.archive.org/web/20160311142457/https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT202064)

Apple developer blog describing functional part of  NSFileProtectionComplete.

```
“NSFileProtectionComplete

        The file is stored in an encrypted format on disk and cannot be read from or written to while the device is locked or booting.”
```

Comment: how to possible encrypted data to Decrypted data objective c

Answer (score 1):

Apple includes support for its CommonCrypto library in iOS, and has [a sample code project](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CryptoExercise/Introduction/Intro.html) to demonstrate use of asymmetric and symmetric encryption/decryption.

Which approach you take depends on how you intend to secure the data; a symmetric approach could require storing the key in the application, which reduces security somewhat. But the sample code should get you started, either way.

Answer (score 0):

Data protection is a feature available for iOS 4 devices that offer hardware encryption: iPhone 4, iPhone 3GS,  iPod touch (3rd generation or later), and all iPad models. This article outlines how to enable and verify data protection.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4175

Hope this helps