# Encrypting SQLite database file on iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data, encryption

My client asked me if it is possible to encrypt his iOS SQLite file.
I checked this two resources:

[Encrypt & Decrypt Sqlite file (Using Core Data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254404/encrypt-decrypt-sqlite-file-using-core-data)
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4175

Please correct me if I'm wrong, the file will be encrypted so no one will be able to crack into it (although it will be possible for a determined cracker I think).

Core Data queries will run as usual right? I mean there is no performance penalty neither a different API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The links you provided talk about encrypting storage across the whole device;  However if the goal is that the user not be able to open the database file directly then will not help you, as the only thing that protects against is your data being accessed in the event the device is stolen.  It also relies on the user to set it up, the app cannot mandate that the device storage is encrypted.

Basically, what is the motivation behind wanting the storage encrypted?

EDIT:

Based on the response chain, I think using the encrypted variant of SQLLite at:

http://sqlcipher.net/

is a good solution.  This encrypts database contents before they hit storage, which is great.  An attacker still might be able to find the key used in your code to decrypt the database, but any layer of defense you can add will help.  I don't think you could use that with CoreData (as it is built atop the built-in sqllite libraries) but you could probably use it with a wrapper like FMDB:

https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

Comment: My client want to encrypt the database file in order to prevent the user from opening the database file directly. What to do in this case?

Comment: The user cannot normally get to the database file, as long as you put it in the Library directory.  A jailbroken user can get to any file.  You cannot use CoreData against an encrypted file.  Your best bet for a compromise might be obsfucation - you could write a few meaningless bytes at the front of the database file when the app was closed or suspended, and remove them when you woke up again.  The downside is if you get the code wrong a user could easily lose all the data it was holding.

Comment: What about http://sqlcipher.net/ ? Could it serves me in this situation? should I expect some obstacles in the AppStore if I employed it? is it allowed?

Comment: What do you mean by writing a few meaningless bytes at the front of the database? Would you please explain this to me? Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: Actually sqlcipher.net looks pretty good, though you could not use it with CoreData I think... but you could probably use it with a wrapper like FMDB.  The byte thing, was just taking the sqllite file that CoreData generates, and writing a few characters in the front of the file so that anything trying to read it would not think it was a valid SQLlite database.   The sqlcipher solution is much more robust.  I would go with that.

Comment: You don't need a jail broken phone to get at user data.  Using the Mac program iExplorer I can freely look at any Apps data.  I use it a lot during development to make sure that my data is being stored correctly.

Comment: @RogerGilbrat in this case, do you have a solution that encrypts the database so that when you copy it using iExplorer and try to access tables, they won't open.

Comment: That will not work, CoreData would not know how to read an encrypted file, so at some point you'd have to de-crypt it to disk where it was visible.  Possibly there's an option in SQLite to enable encryption...