# Is it possible to stop the installed application database access in iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite

i am doing one application.In that i am using sqlite database.I am storing my information in that sqlite file.But when i install my application in device,user able to access the application database file using iExplorer.Using this application,user can change or delete the database? If yes then how to stop this process.

Comment: interesting is this possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you can do is encrypt your data in the database, or find some way to encrypt the whole database file. Look here for some suggestions:

[Encrypting SQLite database file on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753433/encrypting-sqlite-database-file-on-ios)